# Displaying a plot of first elements of array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I have an array:

```
[[5, 6, 9,...], [3, 7, 7,...], [8, 4, 9,...],...]
```

How can I make a plot displaying the first elements of these arrays on the y axis using matplotlib? x axis can be just 1, 2, 3,...

So the plot would have values:

```
x -> y
1 -> 5
2 -> 3
3 -> 8 ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just select first column of an array and plot it with `plt.plot` command like here:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

# test data
a = np.array([[5, 6, 9], [3, 7, 7], [8, 4, 9]])
print(a[:,0]) # result is [5 3 8]

# plot the line
plt.plot(a[:,0])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the first element of lists and then create another list by appending those elements.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

oldList = [[5, 6, 9,...], [3, 7, 7,...], [8, 4, 9,...],...]
newList= []

for element in oldList:
  newList.append(element[0]) #for every element, append first member of that element

print(newList) #not necessary line, just for convenience

plt.plot(newList)
plt.show()
```

[image]